# Using Partial Specialization in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
template<class T, int I=44> struct test {T j = I;};

template<int J> struct test<int, J> {int j = J;};

int main()
{
  test<55> jj;

  std::cout << jj.j << std::endl;
  return(1);
}
```

The compiler (clang) complains only about the line `test<55> jj`

I don't understand why? Is there a work around?

And if it complains about that line, why doesn't it complain about the second template definition?

Thanks in advance.

The message is:

```
enable.cpp:17:8: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
test<55> jj;
   ^~
enable.cpp:9:16: note: template parameter is declared here
template<class T, int I=44> struct test
```

Comment: Could you link the error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't understood how selecting a class template specialization works.

Your specialization:

```
template<int J> struct test<int, J> {int j = J;};
```

does not create a template for which you only have to pass in a single int template parameter.

```
test<55> jj; // doesn't work because there's no template<int J> struct test
```

Instead what it does is create a specialization of `template<class T, int I> struct test` which will be used when the template arguments to `template<class T, int I> struct test` match the specialization, i.e. `test<int,J>`.

```
test<int,55> jj; // uses the specialization template<int J> struct test<int, J>
```

Here's the key quote from the standard:

> In a type name that refers to a class template specialization, (e.g.,
>   `A<int, int, 1>`) the argument list shall match the template parameter
>   list of the primary template. **The template arguments of a
>   specialization are deduced from the arguments of the primary template.** *[emphasis added]*
>
> *— 14.5.5.1 [temp.class.spec.match] p4*

---

You seem to be attempting to set `int` as a default type for `T` while simultaneously setting an independent default value for `I`. I think your intent is to be able to specify a type and a value, specify only a type and get 44 as a default value, or specify only a value and get int as a default type.

Unfortunately I don't know of a way to specify independent defaults like that. You can specify defaults (`template<class T=int, int I=44> struct test`) but getting the default type will also require accepting the default value.

However if you're willing to use a second name then you can do:

```
template <int I>
using test_int = test<int, I>;
```

This creates a template alias such that you only have to specify a value:

```
test_int<55> jj;
```

And this will end up using whatever specialization `test<int, I>` happens to resolve to whether there's an explicit specialization or the compiler generates an implicit one.

Answer (score 3):

The first error occurs because the compiler tries to instantiate the *first* template parameter (`class T`) with 55. This does not work, because 55 is not a type itself, but an instantiation of it. However, `test<int>` works because here the template parater is a type, as requested by your template signature.

What you want instead is "currying" for types, aka. template aliasing:

```
template <typename T>
struct test2 = using test<T, 55>;
```

Here you only need to provide a `T`  to choose 55 as fixed second parameter. But you still need to use that type by giving it a concrete `T`, e.g., `test2<double>`.

The comments indicated you could also be interested in the following variant:

```
template <int I>
using test3 = test<int, I>;
```

Here you fix the first type parameter to int, which allows you to use it as you did in your code:

```
test3<55> t;
```

Comment: There's so many things wrong in the code... First, the syntax obviously fails. Second, he doesn't want to specify the type. Third, that's not partial specialization.

Comment: The specialization fixes T to int, and uses 55 only as the value he happens to be using. You're probably looking for `template <int I> using test_int = test<int, I>;` instead.

Comment: The template aliasing in the answer is equivalent to a default value, which is not what the user really wants.